# Setting a DTO onject that has an Array as an instance variable

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

Is there any method to set a DTO object that has ,an Array as instance variable, at once?
here is the DTO

```
public class AbcDTO {

String label;
Float[] time;
String[] startTime;
//getters and setters 
 }
```

This is the bean class from where i'm trying to set this DTO

```
q = em.createNamedQuery("namedQuery");
        q.setParameter(1, anaId);
        List<Object> objects = new ArrayList();
        objects = q.getResultList();
```

Now List of objects , objects , will contain a list where each element of the list has two fields , time and startTime , from the databse . How can I set the DTO object with the given list .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the current DTO you will have to iterate through the result list, collect the `time` and `startTime` values and assign them to your DTO. JPA does not provide a direct way for this.

What you could do is to change your DTO to have a single `time` and a single `startTime` field. Then you could map a result list to a list of DTOs with a constructor expression:

```
List<AbcDTO2> dtos = em.createQuery("SELECT new com.example.AbcDTO2( o.time, o.startTime) FROM Entity o").getResultList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response ,although i used the other approach to iterate through the result list , but i will keep your approach in mind .